# Skipping or Mocking SecurityUtils during Unit testing

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, spring-security, mockito, spy

I have a REST endpoint that uses the `SecurityUtil.getCurrentUserLogin().get();` method.

I'm building unit tests for this endpoint, and would like to skip over the `SecurityUtil.getCurrentUserLogin()` method, but when I Mock or Spy the class, it throws an error because it's final.

My only other thought is to figure out how to force it to return a value. But I'm having trouble structuring that properly. Something along the lines of `when(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().get()).thenReturn(PresetUserLogin);`

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using `@WithMockUser` from the Spring Security test support? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#test-method-withmockuser

Comment: No, I didn't even know it existed, and this might actually work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eleftheria responded above, and it worked perfectly for my needs.

> Have you considered using `@WithMockUser` from the Spring Security test support? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#test-method-withmockuser